# Clojure For loop index numbers

Tags: for-loop, indexing, clojure

How can I have the index of this for loop in this block of code:

```
(def numbers [:one :two :three :four :five])
(def colors  [:green :red :blue :pink :yellow])
(def letters [:A :B :C :D :E])

(for [x numbers
      i colors
      j letters]
    (println (str x " - " i " - " j)))
```

This code will print 125 lines and I want to have the index number with each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using atoms are discouraged in Clojure, but I think this is the simplest way:

```clj
(let [index (atom 0)]
  (for [x numbers
        i colors
        j letters]
    (do (swap! index inc)
        (println (str @index ": " x " - " i " - " j)))))
```

Comment: `For` returns sequence with 125x `nil`, `doseq` is better. And `swap!` returns a new value of atom, so you can do `(let [index (atom 0)]
  (doseq [x numbers
          i colors
          j letters]
    (println (str (swap! index inc) ": " x " - " i " - " j))))`. The simplest, a little bit slow, but also suitable.

Answer (score 6):

You need [`map-indexed`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed):

```
(def numbers [:one :two :three :four :five])
(def colors  [:green :red :blue :pink :yellow])
(def letters [:A :B :C :D :E])

(->> (for [x numbers
           i colors
           j letters]
       (str x " - " i " - " j))
     (map-indexed (fn [index value] 
                    (str "Index: " index " : " value)))
     (run! println))
```

Shorter version of `(fn [index value] ...)`:

```
(map-indexed #(str "Index: " %1" : " %2))
```

Also consider calling one `println` with one long string instead of calling 125x `println`, it seems to be faster:

```
(->> (for [x numbers
           i colors
           j letters]
       (str x " - " i " - " j))
     (map-indexed #(str "Index: " %1 " : " %2 "\n"))
     str/join
     println)
```

(`str/join` is [`clojure.string/join`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/join))

Comment: You can make the string interpolation cheaper by doing it all at once. Instead of returning a string from the `for` loop, return a function, and call that function with the index: `(->> (for [x numbers, i colors, j letters] (fn [ix] (str "Index: " index ": " x " - " i " - " j))) (map-indexed (fn [ix f] (f ix)) ...)`

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for this. Here are a few:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    ))


(def numbers [:one :two :three :four :five])
(def colors [:green :red :blue :pink :yellow])
(def letters [:A :B :C :D :E])

(verify
  ; The tupelo.core/indexed function will add a 0-based index to each element in a sequence
  (is= (t/indexed [:a :b :c])
    [[0 :a]
     [1 :b]
     [2 :c]]))
```

The `tupelo.core/indexed` function will add a 0-based index to each element in a sequence, which is often handy.

```
(verify
  ; tupelo.core/map-let allows you to assign a local name to each item from multiple sequences
  ; but behaves like `map`, not `for`
  (let [vecs (t/map-let [n numbers
                         c colors
                         l letters]
               [n c l]) ; return a vector containing each item in sequence
        ]
    (is= vecs
      [[:one :green :A]
       [:two :red :B]
       [:three :blue :C]
       [:four :pink :D]
       [:five :yellow :E]])))
```

Using `t/map-let` allows you to give a local name to the elements of each sequence, but does not create the cartesian product like with `for`.

```
(verify
  (t/let-spy-pretty ; or just `let` to suppress the "spy" printing
    [
     ; using (mapv vector ...) will also place each triple into a vector
     vecs     (mapv vector numbers colors letters)

     strs     (mapv #(str/join " - " %) vecs)
     strs-idx (t/indexed strs)
     lines    (t/forv [[the-idx the-str] strs-idx]
                (str the-idx ": " the-str))]
    (is= vecs
      [[:one :green :A]
       [:two :red :B]
       [:three :blue :C]
       [:four :pink :D]
       [:five :yellow :E]])
    (is= strs
      [":one - :green - :A"
       ":two - :red - :B"
       ":three - :blue - :C"
       ":four - :pink - :D"
       ":five - :yellow - :E"])
    (is= strs-idx
      [[0 ":one - :green - :A"]
       [1 ":two - :red - :B"]
       [2 ":three - :blue - :C"]
       [3 ":four - :pink - :D"]
       [4 ":five - :yellow - :E"]])
    (is= lines
      ["0: :one - :green - :A"
       "1: :two - :red - :B"
       "2: :three - :blue - :C"
       "3: :four - :pink - :D"
       "4: :five - :yellow - :E"])))
```

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use [range](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range). `(range 125)` is all the integers 0 to 124 inclusive.

```
(def numbers [:one :two :three :four :five])
(def colors  [:green :red :blue :pink :yellow])
(def letters [:A :B :C :D :E])

(for [x numbers
      i colors
      j letters
      n (range (* x i j))]
    (println (str x " - " i " - " j " line " n)))
```

Comment: Adding n like this doesn't index the existing product of elements, it merely multiplies by another component. In this case, (* x i j) is also meaningless, so it just prints "line 0" at the end of each line.